# Dools processing fail

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I have change set file with following line

```
<change-set xmlns='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xs:schemaLocation='http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd'>
```

It stopped working all of a sudden. I made the change as suggested in one of the drools questions [Drools Change Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010786/drools-change-set)

Now it works with change suggested

```
-Ddrools.schema.validating=false
```

The issue is that sometimes, it just doesn't do drools processing and doesn't throw any exceptions either.

What am I missing here?

I am using drools guvnor 5.3.0 to store the knowledge bases.

Is there a work around with existing version or do I have to change drools version completely?

Comment: Please see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56010786/drools-change-set

Comment: i referred to same question in my post

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that.